# how to parse json array value using json node

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `JsonNode` which contains the following JSON. Inside that `JsonNode` object is an array. In that array there are three fields, one of which, `slaid`, is a list. The other two are strings. Here is the JSON.

```
{
    "SLA": [
        {
            "slaid": [
                "53637cc144ae8b607e089701"
            ],
            "ragindicator": "Red",
            "name": "r1"
        },
        {
            "slaid": [
                "53637d1844ae8b607e089704"
            ],
            "ragindicator": "Amber",
            "name": "a1"
        },
        {
            "slaid": [
                "53637eac44ae8b607e089706"
            ],
            "ragindicator": "Green",
            "name": "g1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse this value. How can I parse it , where `slaid`'s type is `List<String>`? I have tried some ways but I am still unable to find the solution.

Comment: Show the ways you've tried it.

Comment: What do you mean by "parse this value"? What do you want to _do_ with _what_ values?

Comment: I am using iterator, jsonNode.iterator() but i am getting an empty iterator

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way I can see is creating `POJO` classes which fit to your `JSON`:

```
class Slaids {

    @JsonProperty("SLA")
    private List<Slaid> slaids;

    public List<Slaid> getSlaids() {
        return slaids;
    }

    public void setSlaids(List<Slaid> slaids) {
        this.slaids = slaids;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return slaids.toString();
    }
}

class Slaid {

    private List<String> slaid;
    private String ragindicator;
    private String name;

    public List<String> getSlaid() {
        return slaid;
    }

    public void setSlaid(List<String> slaid) {
        this.slaid = slaid;
    }

    public String getRagindicator() {
        return ragindicator;
    }

    public void setRagindicator(String ragindicator) {
        this.ragindicator = ragindicator;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Slaid [slaid=" + slaid + ", ragindicator=" + ragindicator + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Slaids.class));
```

Above program prints:

```
[Slaid [slaid=[53637cc144ae8b607e089701], ragindicator=Red, name=r1], Slaid [slaid=[53637d1844ae8b607e089704], ragindicator=Amber, name=a1], Slaid [slaid=[53637eac44ae8b607e089706], ragindicator=Green, name=g1]]
```

If you want to use `JsonNode` you can do it in this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);
ArrayNode slaidsNode = (ArrayNode) rootNode.get("SLA");
Iterator<JsonNode> slaidsIterator = slaidsNode.elements();
while (slaidsIterator.hasNext()) {
    JsonNode slaidNode = slaidsIterator.next();
    System.out.println(slaidNode.get("slaid"));
    System.out.println(slaidNode.get("ragindicator"));
    System.out.println(slaidNode.get("name"));
}
```

Above program prints:

```
["53637cc144ae8b607e089701"]
"Red"
"r1"
["53637d1844ae8b607e089704"]
"Amber"
"a1"
["53637eac44ae8b607e089706"]
"Green"
"g1"
```